# Rewriting a conditional chain as a sequence of one-liners

Tags: java, conditional-statements

I have this code in Java which controls the main arm of a robot:

```
if (gamepad1.left_stick_y > 50)
{
    mainArm.setDirection(DIRECTION_FORWARD);
    mainArm.setPower(50);
}
else if (gamepad1.left_stick_y < -50)
{
    mainArm.setDirection(DIRECTION_REVERSE);
    mainArm.setPower(50);
}
```

That is only a small part, but there are a ton of conditionals just like that, some with only one statement if the condition is true. Can it be simplified to something like: *[pseudo-code. Don't take it literally. I know it won't work]*

```
if (gamepad1.left_stick_y > 50) mainArm.setDirection(DIRECTION_FORWARD), mainArm.setPower(50);
else if (gamepad1.left_stick_y < -50) mainArm.setDirection(DIRECTION_REVERSE), mainArm.setPower(50);
```

Unfortunately, the libraries used for interfacing directly with the hardware for setting power and such are closed source, so modifying them is out of the question.

Comment: Have you gone ahead and tried within your IDE?

Comment: For the sake of saving an opening and closing brace? Why not just do the same thing as in your first example but remove the line breaks?

Comment: Why do you want to have the if statement in one line?

Comment: Do you really want your code to be unreadable and hard to maintain?

Comment: @adranale - They are simple , and there are a whole lot of them.

Comment: mainArm.setPower(50) can be outside of the if. And you shouldn't try to sacrifice readability for "less lines of code".

Comment: @AndroidDev They are the opposite of simple. They are hard to read and hard to maintain. less lines and less characters does not mean more simplicity.
And if you have too many if statements, you should instead think about restructuring your code to reduce them or grouping them in related groups, for example extracting the ones that handle left_stick_y in a separate method.

Comment: Hint: instead worrying how to make your code less readable, you should do the opposite. Start with reading "clean code" by Robert Martin; just to understand how counter-productive your idea looks like.

Comment: @Jägermeister The number of lines the code occupies has a profound effect on readability, too, because scrolling tends to negatively impact reader's focus, and also because human eyes have limited field of view. That is why reducing code length by a factor of four is a big deal. Adding spaces to format conditionals in nice-looking columns would bring readability back, without the disadvantage of vertical scrolling.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I think the second best thing a programmer can do is *deleting* source code. So I do understand the benefits of getting rid of code. I am only saying that the initial proposal within the question didn't look like an optimal choice to make that code more readable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code would not compile:

```
if (gamepad1.left_stick_y>50) mainArm.setDirection(DIRECTION_FORWARD), mainArm.setPower(50);
//                                                                   ^
```

Your attempt at converting multiple operations into one by placing a comma would not work:

> JLS 15.27: Unlike C and C++, the Java programming language has no comma operator.

One approach is to allow changing power and direction in a single call:

```
if (gamepad1.left_stick_y > 50) mainArm.setDirectionAndPower(DIRECTION_FORWARD, 50);
```

> the libraries for setting power and such are closed source

If you cannot modify the library, you can make your own helper method to address this shortcoming:

```
private static void setDirectionAndPower(Arm arm, Direction dir, int pow) {
    arm.setDirection(dir);
    arm.setPower(pow);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The optimization you propose is a bad one. It is worse than the original. The code becomes less readable and more error prone. If there are multiple such conditions, one may consider a refactoring either by redesigning the logic in a more OOP fashion or by defining a method which would be called from a switch statement...

Comment: And just for the sake of it: switch statements are only minimally "better" than lengthy if/else/if cascades. They look "better organized" in the first place; but they are the wrong answer.

Comment: Yes, switch is just an alternative, but there exist many more like employing a design pattern or not writing that code at all :) (using a 3rd party lybrary)

Answer (score 3):

If you change your setter so it returned `this` then you can chain method calls:

```
public MainArm setDirection(int dir) {
    this.direction = dir;
    return this;
}

if (gamepad1.left_stick_y > 50) mainArm.setDirection(DIRECTION_FORWARD).setPower(50);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Builder Design pattern. Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern at the Java implementation

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ternary Operator:

```
mainArm.setDirection((gamepad1.left_stick_y > 50)?DIRECTION_FORWARD:DIRECTION_REVERSE);
mainArm.setPower(50);
```